# YII2 заполнение textinput от выбранного значения в dropDownList

Tags: yii2

У меня есть заявление на поступление, где родитель из выпадающего списка

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idKids')->dropDownList($arrKids, ['prompt'=>'']) ?>
```

выбирает своего ребенка, нужно сделать так чтобы 
данные о ребёнке автоматически заполнялись в textinput в зависимости от того какого ребенка выбрали

Comment: Надо написать js, который при изменении указанного select получит значение и пропишет его в указанном инпуте. Только вот для чего это писать в инпут, если в селекте уже это есть?